# Vue router beforeEach not called if destination redirect resolves to same path

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a problem when I use `router.push('/')` as the last step of a logout.

If I trigger the logout procedure from the same route that `/` `redirect`s to, the `router.beforeEach` will not be triggered and therefore not redirect the user to the `/login` but still show the route that should only be visible to logged in users (which the user isn't any more at the end of the logout procedure).

```
{
  path: '/',
  redirect: 'foo'
},
{
  path: '/foo',
  name: 'foo',
  component: Foo,
  meta: {
    requiresAuth: true
  }
},
```

and

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  ...
  if(to.requiresAuth && userLoggedIn == false) 
    next('/login')
  ...
```

So if I trigger the logout from any route other than `/foo` it works as expected but if I trigger it from `/foo` the user is **not** redirected to `/login`.

I guess that might possibly be intended behaviour to make the routing as efficient as possible but in this case it is definitely not what I want.

How do I ensure my `beforeEach` route guards will be evaluated on every `router.push/replace`?

Comment: Why would you push the same path on logout? Shouldn't you push the login path? That would definitely trigger `router.beforeEach`, since the path would actually be different.

Comment: I want the user to end up on the main page, not the login page...

Answer (score 3):

Create a `/logout` route which redirects to the `/` route.

Bonus: Display a nice message with "Successfully logged out" and redirect after a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 2):

The `router.beforeEach` guard seems to run only when it detects a change in navigation. Since the route is the same in your case, you'd have to force a navigation change by pushing a different route path before your intended one. Pushing an empty space beforehand works well. *This is admittedly hacky.*

For example:

```
<button @click="$router.push(' '); $router.push('/')">Logout</button>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/4r2o1291v0)

Comment: That's almost what I did for now, but it does feels more like a hack than a clean solution. Would be nice to have the option to trigger a force evaluate of the routes or something...